# Flutter: How can I append row while ignoring what's in the first column? or any column for that matter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-sheets

This is for making API calls from my flutter app to Google Sheets. The calls work fine if everything in my first column is empty. However, I want identifiers in my first column (1, 2, 3, a, b, c). Unfortunately, these numbers and letters are not overlooked and my app starts sending my data to the very bottom of the sheet. I don't want this. I need all date to fill in with my identifiers in column 1.

Here's my code:

```
final secondRow = {
  'DATE': formattedDate,
  'ID': text4,
  'LATITUDE': position.latitude.toString(),
  'LONGITUDE': position.longitude.toString(),
  'NOTES': text5,
  'COUNTER': formattedDate,
};

await sheet.values.map.appendRow(secondRow);
```

The problem is with the last line of code (I think).. How can I ignore the first column and proceed to add data based on all other empty columns?

Comment: Can you try: `await sheet.values.map.appendRow(secondRow,{fromColumn=2,inRange=true});` or `await sheet.values.map.appendRow(secondRow,fromColumn=2,inRange=true);` and let me know if it worked for you and if it did, which one worked.

Comment: too many positional arguments on both.

Answer (score 0):

Should be replaced with:

```dart
await sheet.values.map.appendRow(secondRow, fromColumn: 2, inRange: true);
```